# How to destroy all instances of a object with ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, javascript-framework

I created 2 panels like that with the framework ExtJS (i know it's not the best way):

```
var panel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
                title: "first panel",
                width: 400,
                height: 250,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                html: "test 1"
            });

panel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
                title: "second panel",
                width: 400,
                height: 250,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                html: "test 2"
            });
```

Now I have 2 panels in my browser. And now if I do this:

```
panel.destroy();
```

It destroys only the last one.
So my question is : How can I destroy the first panel? Is there a method which contains all the panels in the browser? Do I store the IDs' panels each time in order to destroy them later?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var objArray = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("Ext.panel.Panel");
```

`objArray` contains all the panel objects.

Now run a `for` loop and destroy all the objects .

Comment: Thanks for your precious help, that's exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you make them different variables (or an array that you manage), you can destroy them individually:

```
var panel1 = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
    ...
});

var panel2 = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
    ...
});

panel1.destroy();
panel2.destroy();
```

Or this:

```
var panels = [];
var panels[0] = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
    ...
});

var panels[1] = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
    ...
});

for (var i=0; i<panels.length; i++)
{
    panels[i].destroy();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevhender. I've tried this methods before my post. Do you know an other way to destroy the 2 "instances" of the instance?

Comment: @RémyJUANES, there is no reason for this code not to work unless you have re-assigned the variables containing your panels to something else.  This code has been tested and works as expected.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i nerver said that your code doesn't work, i was just looking for an other way to do this in order to learn more about ExJs.